# How to pull shared library during build in gitlab-ci docker?

Tags: java, maven, docker, gitlab

I have a simple `gitlab-ci` pipeline. Now I want to add a `maven` dependency to a library that I want to share between different projects, eg my main project defines:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.projects</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The my-commons is also a project in my `gitlab`.

Question: how can I trigger a `mvn clean install` into the ci-repository on that shared dependency during build of my main project?

This is my `gitlab-ci` from main project:

```
image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11

#TODO how to trigger a mvn clean install on my-commons?

test:
  stage: test
  script: mvn test -B

build:
  stage: build
  script: mvn package -B -Dmaven.test.skip=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.jar

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: ...
```

Sidenote: I know I could setup a local shared repository manager like `nexus`, but I'd like to avoid that and simply add the common dependency into the build process.

Comment: The best solution is to start using a repository manager not only for such purposes...

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own image and use it at gitlab-ci.

Example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11

RUN mvn clean install

# ... other stuff
```

after you'll build your image and push it to docker hub you can use it inside your gitlab-ci.

useful links:

- [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)
- [docker image build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/)
- [Pushing a Docker container image to Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/)